# Flutter - Change the color of text in TextField on focus?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to have two different colors on TextField? One - when the focus isn't on the TextField, and the other is?

```
TextStyle editTextStyle =
      const TextStyle(color: Color(0xffaa7420), height: 1),
```

and

```
  InputDecoration inputDecoration = const InputDecoration(focusColor:Colors.black...
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve your result using FocusNode.
First difine a FocusNode

```
FocusNode focus = FocusNode();
```

then use this node in your TextField

```
        TextFormField(
              focusNode: focus,
              onTap: () => {FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus)},
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: focus.hasFocus ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
            )
```

Comment: Your solution is good but I wonder if there's any other way to achieve this? Without rebuild the widget?

Comment: we are not builing the widget again it just a sample, let me make it more clear check updated answer