# How to discover TextField editing being cancelled / keyboard collaped / focus lost

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, bloc

The code below shows 2 text fields. It's a stripped example, just ignore things like `TextEditingController` not being disposed.

If user edits one of the text fields, and presses "Done" on the keyboard, new value is sent to the cubit (saved) and all is good.

However, when - during editing - user clicks on another TextField, or collapses the keyboard, he's left with a very inconsistent state. TextField - the one he was editing - shows value, which wasn't saved, and he's not aware of it.

So how can I either save the value, or restore it back to the original, or do whatever when user just didn't confirm changes and stopped editing?

I tried messing with text controllers, forms, `TextField` and `TextFormField` - no luck. I don't want a *Save* button, and it seems the `onSubmitted` is there for some reason, but I miss `onCancelled` or sth.

Updated: I changed to code to inroduce some interaction between both fields, which better corresponds to my real scenario. Also adding a video of what I get.

`testpage.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'some_cubit.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Test')),
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => SomeCubit(),
        child: BlocBuilder<SomeCubit, SomeState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller:
                        TextEditingController(text: state.min.toString()),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onSubmitted: (s) {
                      BlocProvider.of<SomeCubit>(context).updateMin(s);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller:
                        TextEditingController(text: state.max.toString()),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onSubmitted: (s) {
                      BlocProvider.of<SomeCubit>(context).updateMax(s);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`some_cubit.dart`

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

class SomeCubit extends Cubit<SomeState> {
  SomeCubit() : super(SomeState(0, 10));

  void updateMin(String str) {
    final num = int.tryParse(str) ?? 0;
    emit(SomeState(num, max(num, state.max)));
  }

  void updateMax(String str) {
    final num = int.tryParse(str) ?? 0;
    emit(SomeState(min(num, state.min), num));
  }
}

class SomeState {
  final int min;
  final int max;

  SomeState(this.min, this.max);
}
```

This is what I'm getting. As soon as I stop clicking "Done" on the keyboard, but switch between text boxes directly, everything is in an inconsistent state.

[image]

Comment: to know how to work with focus in TextFormField https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70024603/flutter-change-the-color-of-text-in-textfield-on-focus/70024681#70024681 just check answer

Answer (score 0):

textField has `onChanged` function that it fires each time the user adds a character

Comment: Yes, but how can it help?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).